# Is it possible to elegantly provide instances from Guice assisted injected factories that contain no arguments or equivalent?

Tags: java, guice-3

Okay, so the following code fails. However, if there are multiple potential instances of View, then injecting lots of Provider providers where you want to use them feels clumsy. It may be that this is feasible in my case, however I can imagine that in other cases this isn't great... so I thought I'd ask the question while it was fresh in my mind. One solution I haven't tried yet is adding dummy @Assisted arguments to the method and call like factory.getView1(null), although this also isn't great.

Note, I can see why for the guice implementers this would be a corner case, as guice would have to know not to call the constructor (as it seems to) but instead use the provider (which it technically is aware of). Still, it's better to ask if there is a solution than assume that there isn't. :-)

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


public class GuiceTests {

    static class View1 implements Presenter.View {
        String name = null;
        @Override
        public String getName() { return null; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name ;}
    }
    static class View2 extends View1 {}
    static class Presenter {
        interface View {public String getName();}
        @Inject
        public Presenter(@Assisted View view //, and other injected services
        ){}
    }

    interface Factory{
        Presenter getPresenter(Presenter.View view);
        View1 getView1();
        View2 getView2();
    }

    static class Module extends AbstractModule
    {
        @Provides View1 getView1()
        {
            View1 view1 = new View1(); //or possibly get this from an xml generator
            view1.setName("buddy");
            return view1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure() {

            install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(Presenter.class, Presenter.class)
                    .build(Factory.class));
        }
    }

    /**
     * We're testing the ability here for assisted injected factories
     * to be used to produce entities provided by the module with NO
     * assisted arguments. This way they can conveniently be used in
     * conjuction with other factory assisted methods as shown below.
     * This fails!
     */
    @Test
    public void testAssisted()
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module());

        Factory factory = injector.getInstance(Factory.class);
        View1 view1 = factory.getView1();
        Assert.assertEquals("buddy", view1.getName());
        Presenter presenter = factory.getPresenter(view1);

    }
}
```

**Extra context**

Alan asked below "Can you give an example of what real code that uses this (not calling the injector) would look like? I don't see why you wouldn't just inject the factory and the relevant view together (or define an annotated provides method for each flavour of presenter that did that)"

So I have a presenter that is visualized as a card in a kinda floating layout. This presenter has certain business logic that configures itself with a set of services. There is a 'new' button in the app, it provides you with a view of the card that wizards you through the new process (configuration on the card). Once the card is built, there is a different view to represent the card... but it shares much of the same business logic... so ideally I want to reuse the presenter that is already configured with the model.. but now attach the built view. Persisted cards are recreated with built view.
Please don't read unless you're following that discussion.

Note the above code distills the problems I'm having adequately. Below complicates things as it gives a fuller context.

```
//----------------

//on Add new entity
cardLayout.add(factory.getPresenterWithWizardView());

//-----------
//then later in the finish of the wizard
thePresenter.setView(factory.getConstructedView());
//I would prefer not to create a new presenter here, as the presenter also has layout
//state and logic that maintains and interacts with cardLayout to . Allowing for removing
//and adding a different presenter would trigger stuff affecting the state.

//--------------
//however elsewhere cards are loaded with 
cardLayout.add(factory.getPresenterWithBuiltView(cardFromDb));
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what real code that uses this (not calling the injector) would look like? I don't see why you wouldn't just inject the factory and the relevant view together (or define an annotated provides method for each flavour of presenter that did that).

Comment: You can omit `implement(Presenter.class, Presenter.class)` btw - it's not needed if the two classes are the same.

Comment: I have a presenter that is visualized as a card in a kinda floating layout. This presenter has certain business logic that configures itself with a set of services. There is a 'new' button in the app, it provides you with a view of the card that wizards you through the new process (configuration on the card). Once the card is built, there is a different view to represent the card... but it shares much of the same business logic... so ideally I want to reuse the presenter that is already configured with the model.. but now attach  the built view. Persisted cards are recreated with built view.

Comment: Sorry, don't grok that (code is less ambiguous). I don't see anything in the example above that does anything other than create a new presenter every time `getPresenter` is called.

Comment: Does my ammendment help? The test was written for easy consumption and understanding of the problem. It doesn't necessarily reflect my actual context completely. There's a trade off between recreating a fuller context/taking up too much time/trying people's patience... unfortunately.

Comment: The above amendment is written as if I used my answer below to streamline it. Those methods could always be separated into two just like the first example. I guess this whole question was more of a rant in general, about why my life isn't easier. My no1 reason for posting to stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess besides using lots of Providers directly (injecting them where needed), another method would be to create a SanerFactory class which would have methods like factory.getPresenterWithView1(). This would then be the only place where I might have to inject multiple providers, isolating the use of View1 & View2 implementations directly. Just a pity that there would be more boiler plate to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Where you know there are specific views that you want presenters for, I would just add to your module something like this:

```
@Provides @Named("PresenterForView1")
public Presenter forView1(Factory factory, View1 view1) {
  return factory.getPresenter(view1);
}
```

(Only with a proper annotation rather than a name, and repeating for the various canned views.)

Where you later want to change the presenter's view I'd just inject that View:

```
@Inject Constructor(@Named("PresenterForView1") Presenter presenter, View2 view2) {
  ...
  presenter.setView(view2);
  ...
}
```

(Or possibly inject `Provider<View2>` if you don't want it constructed in advance.)

Comment: Thanx for your response, but this basically states what I wrote in my answer. Then you'll have to pass a Provider<View1>, Provider<View2> etc where ever injected. A negative consequence (but liveable) is that in order to do this it hardcodes the View type, in the case where I move from JavaFx to GWT a later date (although probably not worth speculating on for my project). If I did have multiple providers like this, I'd prefer to isolate this and expose merely Views in a SanerFactory class as described.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer any better than your question, it seems. I don't think there's a better way with Guice. Wrapping up the injection and logic in a separate class is certainly reasonable.

Comment: (If you do move to GWT, you know that Gin provides similar functionality as Guice?)

Comment: Sorry, I should have written my answer more clearly. "besides using lots of Providers directly", meant directly injecting the providers of View1,2 etc where they were needed, as opposed to only injecting them in SanerFactory, and then injecting SanerFactory where needed. Thanx, I know Gin provides similar compile time functionality. What I wanted to avoid was using View1 & View2 throught the code, rather than just using View. SanerFactory would at least isolate this.